# is there anything like carriage return in python that works in idle python for a countdown timer

Tags: python-3.x

```
import time

while True:
    uin = input(">> ")
    try:
      when_to_stop = abs(int(uin))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
      break
    except:
      print("Not a number")

    while when_to_stop > 0:
      m, s = divmod(when_to_stop, 60)
      h, m = divmod(m, 60)
      time_left = str(h).zfill(2) + ":" + str(m).zfill(2) + ":" + str(s).zfill(2)
      print(time_left + "\r", end='')
      time.sleep(1)
      when_to_stop -= 1
    print()
```

I know that carriage return doesn't work in python idle so I was wondering if there was another way that does the excact same thing and the carriage function but works in python idle
thank you for your help

using python 3.6 if you need to know

Comment: you want it to return to the start of the same line? idle isn't really a console it's an ide so if there is something like it would be mentioned somewhere in the idle docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/idle.html but i doubt such a feature exists since again, its not a console